# How to show button depending on the string value in <td> tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, angular-ngmodel

I am making an Angular project, I have this list of data I am fetching from a database using WebAPI. I want to display those details on my html page using a table. Now one of column I have to show 2 buttons depending on the value of one of column which is a string. I tried using `ngif="{{product.Status}}=="Some string`, button it didn't work! And my component is written on typescript.please suggest what to do!

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with C# or Asp.NET...

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
{{product.Status=="some String" ? "button 1": "button 2"}}
```